# Assigning from string slice creates new instance?

Tags: python, string

```
 mystr = 'abvd'
 mysubstring = mystr[1:2]
```

In the above code, is there new allocation done for assigning to `mysubstring`?

(`mysubstring` could "point" to same chunk of memory that was created for `mystr`)

Comment: Yes there is a new allocation.

Comment: It could, but then mysubstring would be 'corrupt' if you were to delete mystr

Comment: Check out http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the id() method on both instances and see that the id you get is different.

Answer (score 0):

Run those two lines in http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html. You'll see the two allocations in the global frame.

```
>>> mystr = 'abvd'
>>> mysubstring = mystr[1:2]
```

In contrast:

```
>>> mystr = ['a', 'b', 'v', 'd']
>>> mysubstring = mystr[1:2]
```